# Custom TOC number entering in Koma-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook

I am using the `scrbook` class and I (for some reasons) need to redefine the commands `\thesection` and etc. The problem is that this modifies the TOC entries. And I want to restore the TOC entries to the normal format, i.e,

1. Chapter

1.2 Section

1.2.3 Subsection

but now I just have:

1. Chapter
2. Section
3. Subsection

I solved this problem for the headers by redefining the command `\sectionformat`, but I did not find any equivalent command to the TOC entries.

```
      \documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
       
        
        \usepackage{scrextend}
        
        \usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} % instead of fancyhdr
        \renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
        \renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
        \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
        \renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
        \renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
        \renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}
        \renewcommand*\sectionformat{\thechapter.\thesection\enskip}
        \renewcommand*\subsectionformat{\thechapter.\thesection.\thesubsection\enskip}
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{One}
    \section{two}
    \subsection{three}
    \chapter{One}
    \section{two}
    \subsection{three}
    \chapter{One}
    \section{two}
    \subsection{three}
    \chapter{One}
    \section{two}
    \subsection{three}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The desired output seems strange to me and I do not suggest to use different numbers in headings, page header and ToC.

If you want to change the numbers in headings and references redefine `\addsectiontocentry` and `\addsubsectiontocentry` to restore the numbers in ToC to the original format:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
%\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{\thechapter.\thesection\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionmarkformat}{\thechapter.\thesection.\thesubsection\enskip}

\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{section}{\thechapter.#1}{#2}}
}

\renewcommand*{\addsubsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocentrydefault{subsection}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{subsection}{\thechapter.\thesection.#1}{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\section{two}
\subsection{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{two}
\subsection{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{two}
\subsection{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{two}
\subsection{three}
\end{document}
```

---

If you only want to change the numbers in the headings and not in page header, ToC and references, then you can redefine `\sectionformat` etc.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}\autodot\enskip}

\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\arabic{section}\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand{\subsectionformat}{\arabic{subsection}\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionformat}{\arabic{subsubsection}\autodot\enskip}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}% numbered subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}% ToC entries for subsubsections

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remark: Do not load package `scrextend` with a KOMA-Script class. Package `scrextend` provides some basic KOMA-Script features for usage with other classes.

Comment: Thanks @esdd for your answer! In my document, I have some special issues (mostly related with cross-reference and label of parts of texts) and because of these issues, I needed to redefined the commands `\thechapter` and etc. My question is, with these redefined commands, i.e., `\thechapter` to `\arabic{chapter}` and etc., how can I put the ToC entries as `\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}\endskip` ?

Comment: @TheEndofTheWorld See my updated answer.

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thank you very much!